# The past of run, ran, has also the meaning of crash into something?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, past-tense, phrasal-verbs

*I drove off the road and ran into a tree.*

In some of my texts of English studies, there is this expression, and the meaning of **ran** is related to a crash in this phrase, is this correct? I didn't find any info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb **to run into** has several [possible meanings](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run-into), one of which is "to accidentally hit or collide with something." This applied to any tense of the verb, not just the past.

The verb **to run** does not mean "to crash" except in this particular construction with **into**. If you follow the link above,  you'll see that even with **into**, it doesn't always mean a physical collision. If I say, "I **ran into** Bob at the grocery store yesterday," it's very likely that I just met him unexpectedly, not that we crashed into each other.

Comment: Nice approach, i really understand it!

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I don't think of this as a special meaning of *run*. But *into* still means *into*.

You can run into a tree. You can walk into a wall. You can fall into a hole. You can fly into a mountain. All of these involve a collision. But I'd consider that a sense of the meaning of *into*, not special meanings of the different verbs used with it.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciated your answer as well!